# Backgroundworker open a second window owned by main window

Tags: c#, wpf, backgroundworker

I 'm facing with this problem: I have two windows (mainwindow, and custommessage). In my code I need to use a backgroundworker. In the Dowork method I want to open the second window (custommessage) that has the same size (width/height) of the mainwindow. Since I don't know the size of the main window I need to make the second window owned by the first one.
That's my code:

```
    private void Starter_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        string linkaddress = Address.Text;

        BackgroundWorker CheckValidAddressBW = new BackgroundWorker();
        CheckValidAddressBW.DoWork += CheckValidAddressBWDoWork;
        CheckValidAddressBW.RunWorkerCompleted += CheckValidAddressBWComplete;
        CheckValidAddressBW.RunWorkerAsync(linkaddress);
    }

    static void CheckValidAddressBWDoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        string bandaddress =""+ e.Argument;
        bool isValid = false;
        /* STUFF INSIDE */
        e.Result = isValid;
    }
    static void CheckValidAddressBWComplete(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        bool result =(bool) e.Result;
        if(result==false)
        {
            CustomMessage cm = new CustomMessage ();
            cm.Width = 800;                
            cm.Height = 600;
            cm.Show();
        }
    }
```

So in this code what I want to do is something like this:

```
        if(result==false)
        {
            CustomMessage cm = new CustomMessage {Owner=this}; //WHERE this means the mainwindow
            cm.Width = this.ActualWidth;                
            cm.Height = this.ActualHeight;
            cm.Show();
        }
```

Since I'm using a backgroundworker I can't use the word "this". So I'm wondering if there's a way to do this.
Thank you in advance.

N.b. I hope my problem it's clear :)

Comment: I'm not sure what you want to do but if you remove the "static" from the two methods you will be able to use "this"

Comment: Thank you for your answer. That was exactly what I was looking for :) I use static very often when I use bacgroundworkers, so I didn't realize that it will create problems :)

Comment: Which version of .NET framework do you use?

Comment: Actually I'm using NET 4,5

Answer (score 0):

I think that you need to pass the mainwindow object as the one of the BackgroundWorker's arguments.
Here I used Tuple objects for example, but you may need to create more appropriate class object:

```
private void Starter_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var linkaddress = Address.Text;

    BackgroundWorker CheckValidAddressBW = new BackgroundWorker();
    CheckValidAddressBW.DoWork += CheckValidAddressBWDoWork;
    CheckValidAddressBW.RunWorkerCompleted += CheckValidAddressBWComplete;
    CheckValidAddressBW.RunWorkerAsync(Tuple.Create<string, Window>(linkaddress, this));
}
static void CheckValidAddressBWDoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    Tuple<string, Window> args = e.Argument as Tuple<string, Window>;
    string bandaddress = args.Item1;
    bool isValid = false;
    /* STUFF INSIDE */
    e.Result = Tuple.Create<bool, Window>(isValid, args.Item2);
}
static void CheckValidAddressBWComplete(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    Tuple<bool, Window> args = e.Result as Tuple<bool, Window>;
    bool result = args.Item1;
    if (result == false)
    {
        CustomMessage cm = new CustomMessage { Owner = args.Item2 };
        cm.Width = 800;
        cm.Height = 600;
        cm.Show();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with less code using Tasks

```
private void Starter_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        Task<bool> taskA = new Task<bool>(() => { return IsValid(); });
        taskA.ContinueWith((ss) =>
        {
            if (ss.Result)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Showing Window");
            }
        });
        taskA.Start();
}

private bool IsValid()
{
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000);
        return true;
}
```

Or since you use .NET 4.5 could can use asunc/await

```
private async void Starter_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        bool res = await Task.Factory.StartNew<bool>(() => { return IsValid(); });
        if (res)
            MessageBox.Show("Showing Window");
}

private bool IsValid()
{
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000);
        return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you want your handlers to have specific knowledge of the instance of your class just don't make them static, make them instance methods.  Since you're attaching the handlers from another instance method the handler will invoke that method *on that instance*, thus ensuring that those handlers have a `this` reference that refers to the instance you care about.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
System.Windows.Application.Current.MainWindow
```